# How to remove volume HUD on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, volume, mpvolumeview

I have made a customrenderer to render a MPVolumeView inside of a xamarin.forms app. Whenever I adjust the volume, I get this big system HUD on screen that is blocking the content on screen. Looks something like this:
[image]

How do I remove this? This is my custom renderer:

```
public class AudioOutputViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AudioOutputView, UIView>
{
    MPVolumeView view;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AudioOutputView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(54, 66, 94);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            view = new MPVolumeView()
            {
                ShowsRouteButton = false,
                ShowsVolumeSlider = true

            };

            SetNativeControl(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change true to false : ShowsVolumeSlider = true

Comment: "Hide" the `MPVolumeView` in your view (it has to present in the View hierarchy)  and programmatically set the `Value` property on it based upon another slider.

Comment: @jdweng This hides the slider entirely.

Comment: @SushiHangover There is no property that is named value. I cant find anything else that would be similar either.

Comment: @LucaPanjer MPVolumeView is a composite view, Value is on the UISlider within a subview, search SO for "how to programmatically without showing system sound bar" (or something like that) under the iOS tag (I do not have the C# code in front of me as I'm on a mobile right now)

Comment: You ask for it to be removed and setting it false does exactly that.  You can move the position of Control if you just want it moved.

Comment: @jdweng I mean the big gray HUD area with the volume on that appears. When I set the property to false, all that gets removed is the slider itself, then you can't control the volume anymore.

Comment: @SushiHangover I managed to do this, but that big gray block from the system is still appearing whenever I change the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt understand perpose of the `AudioOutputViewRenderer`

But to hide the `MPVolumeView` you need next:

in your IosProject -> `AppDelegate` -> method `FinishedLaunching` add next code

```
        var volumeView = new MPVolumeView(new CGRect(-1000,0,0,0));// -1000 will hide your view  from user 
        volumeView.ClipsToBounds = true;
        var slider = volumeView.Subviews.First(x => x is UISlider) as UISlider;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.AddSubview(volumeView);
```

After you can use var `slider` to change volume like this

```
        slider.Value = [your vlm];
```